# Aggregating with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, aggregate, data-science

I've a pandas dataset with two columns :

- Poblacion (city)
- patologie (pathologies)

I would like to show per each city the most 5-6 frequent patologies

```
hlt_downsampled_eng.groupby('Poblacion')['patologie'].count().nlargest(6)
```

My idea would be an output like this :

```
    Barcellona
         Fever 5230
         Rheum 2000
         headache 300
         cough 240
    Tessara
         diarrhea 5230
         flu 1000
         headache 300
         cough 240
```

How can I achieve it with pandas?

I know that I should do :
Group per city > group per pathology > count num of pathologies > aggregate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try groupby twice:

```
# value_counts makes more sense to me
(hlt_downsampled_eng.groupby('Poblacion')['patologie'].value_counts()
                    .groupby('Poblacion').nlargest(6)                 # head(6) should also work
)
```

Comment: good answer, worked like a charm. I thought to do a double group by, but not in this way